# Are Github Actions secrets secure when used in build action

Tags: angular, github, github-actions

I've had a look at the [security hardening for Github Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/security-hardening-for-github-actions#:%7E:text=Sensitive%20values%20should%20never%20be,are%20encrypted%20before%20reaching%20GitHub.), but I wasn't able to figure out if secrets are safe when used in a build action.

The example CI/CD workflow I'm talking about could look like this:

```
  - name: Configure environments
    run: npm run configure:ci

  - name: Build
    run: npm run build:ci
    env:
      API_URL:                   ${{ secrets.API_URL }}
      FIREBASE_API_KEY:          ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_API_KEY }}
      FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN:      ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN }}
      FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL:     ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL }}
      PROJECT_ID:                ${{ secrets.PROJECT_ID }}
      STORAGE_BUCKET:            ${{ secrets.STORAGE_BUCKET }}
      FIREBASE_SENDER_ID:        ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SENDER_ID }}
      FIREBASE_APP_ID:           ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_APP_ID }}
      FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID:   ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID }}
      ANGULAR_FIRE_EMAIL:        ${{ secrets.ANGULAR_FIRE_EMAIL }}
      ANGULAR_FIRE_PASSWORD:     ${{ secrets.ANGULAR_FIRE_PASSWORD }}

  - name: Configure app.yaml
    run: npm run app-config:ci

  - name: Deploy an App Engine app
    id: deploy-app
    uses: google-github-actions/deploy-appengine@main
    with:
      project_id: ${{ secrets.PROJECT_ID }}
      credentials: ${{ secrets.GCP_CREDENTIALS }}
      deliverables: app.yaml
      promote: true
```

As part of the Configure environment step, the secrets are used when generating a persisted [environment.ts](https://angular.io/guide/build) file for use in the future build/deploy steps. You can read more about doing that [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-secure-angular-environment-variables-for-use-in-github-actions-39c07587d590) and [here](https://medium.com/@ferie/how-to-pass-environment-variables-at-building-time-in-an-angular-application-using-env-files-4ae1a80383c).

My question then is, is it possible for someone to access the resultant build files generated by this Github Action? Or is the build server inaccessible? I'm comfortable that the secrets will be redacted in the logs when used, but I'm concerned that they could be accessed via the build server.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you've configured your GitHub Actions runners.
GitHub-hosted runners are ephemeral. These runner virtual machines are discarded after running a GitHub Actions job. In this case, the file would only be available to all the steps in the workflow. So if a dependency is malicious, it will be able to read the file. The file won't be available to any other GitHub Actions workflow runs.
On the other hand, if you're using self-hosted runners, your runner VMs can be persistent. Persistent VMs would retain files like *environment.ts*, and these files would be available for subsequent workflow runs on the VM. Also, a malicious dependency from a previous job can persist on the VM and steal the file once it's created by your workflow run.